# Web Api 2: NotFound() with content?

Tags: asp.net, rest, http-status-code-404, asp.net-web-api2, api-design

I have the following resource used to return specific company information:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{companyId:Guid}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(Guid companyId)
{
    var company = CompanyRepository.Find(companyId);

    if (company == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    else
    {
        var responseModel = new CompanyResponseModel()
        {
            CompanyId = company.Id,
            Name = company.Name
        };

        return Ok(responseModel);
    }
}
```

**Why can we not include content into the `NotFound()` call?**

For example, I would like to include an error response model with a message "Company ID does not exist".

Is this perhaps against RESTful design?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [RFC2616 Section 10](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) the 404 does not return any information about the resource itself.
But if you want to use the 404 you can use this instead:

```
return Content(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Your Content/Message");
```

Comment: To be fair the RFC says "No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent" so, for example, if you have a URI `/api/items/1/subItems/2` it's helpful to indicate where the 404 originated... The RFC also says "This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable." and in this case no other response is applicable.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, works well, sets the Content-Type header and properly serialises the content, too.